# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Is jQuery Mobile included by default?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to know whether jQuery Mobile comes pre-bundled in IBM Worklight; If so what is the meaning of this line, that is included in the main HTML file of a new application:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
```

Also, Without this statement:

```
<script src="jQueryLib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

jQuery does not seem to work for me; it throws an error $ not defined. Am I doing everything correctly or is this the way it is??

And I am getting a weird error that no one else would get,I am trying to include .js files via html and I am pretty sure the syntax is perfect but the js events never fire up, all of these things happen at once and I suspect all these issues are because of one problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood some things, allow me to clarify:

1. **jQuery != jQuery Mobile**

   - Worklight 6.0.0.x is bundled with **jQuery** 1.9
   - Worklight is **not** bundled with jQuery **Mobile**
   - Please refer to the following training module: [Working with UI frameworks](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/03_03_Working_with_UI_frameworks.pdf) (in your case, how to use jQuery Mobile in a Worklight project)
2. Quote from the training module:

> The Worklight client side framework  uses the jQuery library for internal
>   functionality.
>   By default, the $ char is assigned to the internal
>   jQuery  in the application's main HTML file.

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
```

> If your application does
>   not require  jQuery, or if you want to use a  different version of
>   jQuery,  you can remove this line.

If you remove the above line from the HEAD of the main HTML file, and do not include any other version of jQuery instead, then the bundled jQuery will stop working which could account for the problems you are facing.

My suggestion:

1. Do not remove the line
2. Read the training material to understand how to properly add and use jQuery Mobile in the project

Comment: I undestand that JqueryMobile is not Jquery but having jQueryMobile alone does not help me, means I get the $ error still. If Jquery is included by default it should work right?

Comment: One more thing should I include that line in all my html files?? or doing it once in the main html file would suffice??'

Comment: Why do you not read the training module? It clearly states that jQuery is bundled in Worklight. Yes, jQuery is bundled in Worklight. No, you should not include this line in all your files but only in the main HTML file in which is it already included. My answer has replied your questions. If you get errors, you need to expand on them. Please open a different question for those.

Comment: I read the training module completely, I have fixed all the issues thanks for the help.

Comment: Great news! If you could please mark this answer as Answered, thanks.

Comment: I am very much new to web technologies such as jquery mobile/css so was taking help from a web designer, it was his idea to include jQuery.